# How to add a file lock to all existing files in directory

Tags: 7, files

I've just started using [file lock](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_lock) to prevent images getting deleted, so we can build up a store of images for use at a later date. I think this module will solve a problem I've had, but only for images uploaded *from this point forward*.

How can I *also* apply this protection retrospectively to:

1. Images already in file fields
2. Images uploaded by FTP (well, you know, SFTP )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To add a file_lock usage record for all existing files without one:

```
INSERT INTO file_usage (fid, module, `type`, id, `count`)
SELECT fid, 'file_lock' module, 'module' `type`, 0 id, 1 `count`
FROM file_managed 
WHERE status AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT id FROM file_usage
  WHERE file_managed.fid = file_usage.fid
        AND `type`='module'
        AND id=0
        AND `module` = 'file_lock'
        AND `count`>0
);
```

### To add a file_lock record for all files in a directory that are NOT registered in the file_managed table

Here I loop through all likely image files in and write them as `public://` `file_managed` records if none exists.

- preg_ls is not PHP/Drupal core - [nicked it from PHP comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php#60562) - v useful!
- I exclude the `styles/` directory which stores the variants made by different
  image styles. I also exclude the `images/backup/` directory - this is
  particular to my needs, but I left the code in as you'll likely have
  something to exclude too.
- This assumes you have no `private://` files and that everything under sites/default/files is to be a `public://` file. **do not run this as it is if you use private files at all!**
- It also assumes that on `file_save`, `file_lock` will add its own lock (based on your config for `file_lock`).

And now the code:

```
$dir = DRUPAL_ROOT . "/sites/default/files/";
foreach (preg_ls($dir, true, '/\.(jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)$/i') as $_) {

  $_ = substr($_, strlen($dir));
  if (preg_match('@^(styles/|images/backup/)@', $_)) {
    continue;
  }

  $uri = "public://$_";
  if (!db_query("SELECT fid FROM {file_managed} WHERE uri = :uri",[':uri' => $uri])->rowCount()) {
    $file = new stdClass();
    $file->fid = NULL;
    $file->uri = $uri;
    $file->filename = drupal_basename($uri);
    $file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($file->uri);
    $file->uid = $user->uid;
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($file);
  }
}
```